# Data not showing up in the gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have two gridviews in my asp.net page. Where the datas are coming from two different databases. In that, one gridview has select row function. Now what I want to do is, I need to generate my 3rd gridview row by row according to the selection of the 1st gridview's 2 cell and the 2nd gridview 1st column data(1st column data is common for all the rows).

**This is my code:**

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();

var EmpID = (Label)grdEmp.SelectedRow.Cells[1].FindControl("lblEmpID");
var firstName = (Label)grdEmp.SelectedRow.Cells[1].FindControl("lblFirstName");
var date = DateTime.Now.ToString();
var planID = (Label)grdPlanID.Rows[0].Cells[1].FindControl("lblPlanID");

string empid = Convert.ToString(EmpID.Text);
string first = Convert.ToString(firstName.Text);
string Date = Convert.ToString(date);
string planid = Convert.ToString(planID.Text);
dt.Columns.Add("Emp_ID", typeof(string));
dt.Columns.Add("First_Name", typeof(string));
dt.Columns.Add("Created_Time", typeof(string));
dt.Columns.Add("Plan_ID", typeof(string));

DataRow dtrow = dt.NewRow();    // Create New Row
dtrow["Emp_ID"] = empid;            //Bind Data to Columns
dtrow["First_Name"] = first;
dtrow["Created_Time"] = Date;
dtrow["Plan_ID"] = planid;
dt.Rows.Add(dtrow);

grdList.DataSource = dt;
grdList.DataBind();
```

Comment: And your question is....?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get values from two gridviews to populate in another gridview](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26689705/get-values-from-two-gridviews-to-populate-in-another-gridview)

Comment: @Tim the question is, values are not showing up on the gridview. Why?

Comment: @rikitikitik well, I didn't got any answer for that question as well.

Comment: are you calling this method on page load?